# Laravelで新しいプロジェクトを始めるには？

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

プログラミング初心者、Laravel学習二日目の者です。

教本の本当に基礎的な練習を終えた状態です。（web.phpでルーティング設定、コントローラ作成して、phpファイルの演習、localhost:8000/やlocalhost:8000/helloの表示）

ここから自身の新しいプロジェクトを始めるには、インストール直後に行った

```
laravel new プロジェクト名
```

をコマンドで行えばいいのでしょうか？

環境：
Laravel 5
Windows10

Comment: 「LaravelはPHPベース」なのは周知の事実なので、タイトルは質問内容を具体的に説明するものにした方が良いかなと思います (例えば今回なら「Laravelで新しいプロジェクトを始めるには？」など) / 質問は後からでも [編集] できますので、ぜひ見直してみてください。

Comment: 無知で失礼いたしました、勉強になります、訂正致しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのコマンドで大丈夫です。

プロジェクトはコマンドを実行したディレクトリに作られるので、ディレクトリをしっかり確認してから
コマンドを実行することをおすすめします。

詳しくはこちらをご覧ください。
　　https://readouble.com/laravel/5.6/ja/installation.html

Comment: ディレクトリ確認しっかり行います。参考ページもありがとうございます。